# background image staying put with divs

Tags: html, css

How can I get my background to act `position: absolute;` as my few div elements on top of it? I'm trying to make it so at different screen resolutions my div elements and background stay in sync. Below is the small code I have implemented thus far.

```
<!doctype html><head>

<title>Coming Soon! </title></head>



<style>

* { 

padding: 0px;
margin: 0px; 
}

#searchfold {
    background: url("../imgs/search_box.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 335px;
    margin-left: 173px;
    margin-top: 135px;
    width: 890px;
    position: absolute;

}


#bottomfoldbox {
    background: url("../imgs/bottom_foldbox.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 335px;
    margin-left: 173px;
    margin-top: 750px;
    width: 890px;
    position: absolute;
}

#searchfield {
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 178px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    width: 296px;
}


</style>


</head>

<body style="background-image: url('http://mysite.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/mysite_Homepage.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; height: 1055px; position: relative;">


<div id="searchfold">

<div id="searchfield">
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
<input type="text" name="user" style="height:40px; width:200px;"/>
<INPUT type="image" name="search" src="../imgs/search_btn.png" border="0" style=" float: right;
    margin-right: -130px;
    margin-top: -19px;}"></form>
</div>

</div>



</div>


<div id="bottomfoldbox">


</div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Where's the opening `<html>` tag? *(Note: `DOCTYPE`s don't count.)*

Comment: Still no such luck, thanks for the response though!

Comment: I didn't say it would *fix your problem*, just that your markup was flawed to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend you to use media queries to treat different screen resolution properly